# Stacked Area Plot Y-axis not reflecting actual data points: with reproducible example

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have added a reproducible example for my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62945310/stacked-area-plot-y-axis-not-reflecting-actual-data-points).

I'm trying to get a plot similar to this:

[image: Stacked Area Plot]

```
library(ggplot2)

Date <- as.numeric(rep(seq(2000:2005), each = 5))
value <- runif(30,0,100)
group <- rep(LETTERS[1:5],times = 6)
data <- data.frame(Date,value,group)

ggplot(data, aes(x = Date, y = value, fill = group)) + 
  geom_area()
```

Answer (score 1):

Do I understand correctly that you want the areas to overlap instead of getting stacked?

Is this what you want?

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Date, y = value, fill = group)) + 
  geom_area(position = "identity", alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]